# NGINX React Single Page Site - Won't serve CSS from subfolder

Tags: reactjs, nginx, single-page-application

Folder structure is /var/www/test.website.org/app/assets and /var/www/test.website.org/app/index.html. There is an index.html file in the root. Nginx.conf contains

```
    server_name test.website.org;
    root /var/www/test.website.org;
    index index.html;

    location /app {
        try_files $uri /app/index.html;
    }
```

This URL will partially resolve: https://test.website.org/app/asset/0ba6c35604ad11ea99d50242ac110004

Expectation in this case is that the file does not exist and /app/index.html will be rendered. In fact, the index.html is rendered but the CSS in the assets folder is not.